# Time and Work ::

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A and B can do a work in 5 days B and C can do a work in 4 Days.A start  the Work and leave after 4 Days Then B joined and left after 3 days .Remaining work done by C in how many Days

I Have tried:

A and B can do a piece of work in 1 Day is  1/5

similarly B and C is 1/4

**After that I am not able to proceed with this sum, Please anyone guide me for the Answer**

Comment: pls share what is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A,B,C$ does $1/x,1/y,1/z$ part of the in $1$ day. Then

$1/x+1/y=1/5$ and $1/y+1/z = 1/4$.

Let $C$ work for $d$ days. Then by problem $4/x+3/y+d/z=1$.

Now find the value of $d$ using the constraints.

Comment: ok thank you @user8795

Comment: @user8795,pls tell what is the answer